# Access laravel migration and return the return the Blueprint table object

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I wonder if there is a way that I can access the Blueprint in migration file and return it in a external file. Example, I have the following USERS migration:

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

So I wonder if I could "access" this object to use it in a external file. Imagine I have a file get_data_from_migration.blade.php and I could do something like:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

$table = Migration('migrationName');
var_dump($table);
```

So it would print the user table Blueprint on the screen. 
I know it would not be the correct sintax but I use it only to ilustrate the idea.

Anyway, what I need is to print on the screen something like:

You colums in the table are:

- id
- name
- email
- email_verified_at
- password

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

// for your User model
$table = $user->getTable();
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing($table);
```

Or if you don't have an instance of `User` you could try:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

$table = with(new User)->getTable();
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing($table);
```

Or if you just want it for the one model you could just hard code the table name.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

$columns = Schema::getColumnListing('users');
```

Comment: first and third example cant find Schema. second returns only a string "users"

Comment: Yes, you need to import the `Schema` facade class. I've updated the answer to include that.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to "use" it but probably did something wrong. Now it work thank you. Any chance to get the type now? Something like (id-increments), (name-string)

Comment: When you install the `doctrine/dbal` package, you can use `DB::connection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTables()` and other methods to get information about your database structure.